# Ubuntu SDK click package error: Could not find compiled binaries for architecture 'armhf'

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, compiling, ubuntu-sdk

I've recently had this error when trying to build a click package for the latest SDK (15.04.1).

The app I am trying to build a click for is https://launchpad.net/deliverytracker

The app hasn't been changed in any way that should affect the build, but I get the compile error:

> :-1: warning: lint:control_architecture_specified_needed: Could not
>   find compiled binaries for architecture 'armhf'

When trying to build click for Ubuntu SDK armhf (ex: for my Nexus 4).

The app builds and runs fine locally, however, this error prevents the store from taking the click package, so I have to figure out what's causing this.

Any help or ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: I've switch back to compiling for architecture "all" in the click manifest, and it produces the same error on upload:

found binaries for architecture 'all': share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/deliverytracker.mo, share/lo usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/deliverytracker/main/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc, usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/deliverytracker/main/__pycache__/test_main.cpython-34.pyc, usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/deliverytracker/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc lint_control_architecture_valid_contents

except this timeit found the binaries, but still won't pass click verification.